# How can I add more samples to Amazon.YesIntent?

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-slot, alexa-internet

I'm trying to add more samples in my Amazon.YesIntent in order to can catch more than only simple 'yes' response, but when I add more option in the samples node, It doesn't work, It only works with 'Yes'

I tried to add more samples, like this:

This is my Yes interaction model node:

`{ "name": "AMAZON.YesIntent", "samples": [ "sure", "of course", "yes, I want to play again" ] },`

Comment: Can you please include the error details if any or full code to get the help over here ?

Answer (score 2):

Remove the comma from your third sample utterance, then save and build the interaction model and test again.  Make sure there are no build errors.

I suspect your skill didn't build successfully after you added your extra sample utterances, so you're still testing with the "raw" intent and your custom samples aren't in the model.

Your samples (without the comma) all work OK in a test skill I just built, along with some others I added. [image: my test skill]

Comment: Great answer :)